# Why does first line of <pre><code> text display with some indent when formatting is changed with CSS?

Tags: html, css, text-indent

I'm trying to change the appearance of code sections on my Joomla 4 website using the Cassiopeia template. A sample HTML source looks like this:

```
<p>Trying to format a code section below.</p>
<pre><code>This is code line 1, starting at position 1
This is code line 2, starting at position 1 as well
This is code line 3, starting at position 1 as well
</code></pre>
<p>This text follows the code section.</p>
```

Without adding user CSS, this is displayed as follows:

[image: Screen shot with standard formatting]

All lines are left-aligned, as expected.

I'm adding the following CSS to the user.css file:

```
pre {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--cassiopeia-color-primary, #111 );
    scrollbar-color: #ccc transparent;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

pre > code {
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    text-indent: 0;
    color: #111;
    white-space: inherit;
    margin: 20px 20px;
}
```

The CSS (mostly) works as desired, i.e display the code in a bordered box with grey background. However, the first code line is indented by 2 characters. See here:

[image: screen shot with own formatting]

I tried to find the cause using Firefox Web Inspecting Tools (shift-crtl-i), but can't seem to find out. What is causing that 2 character indent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your code a bit, remove margins from styles for the code element and make it a block element:

```css
pre {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--cassiopeia-color-primary, #111 );
    scrollbar-color: #ccc transparent;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

pre > code {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    text-indent: 0;
    color: #111;
    white-space: inherit;
}
```

The `<code>` element is inline by default.

Comment: Thanks. I just had to remove the `margin`. Didn't think of `<code>` being inline by default, and the effect margin has on inline objects.